# How to redirect non www to www on ngnix?

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting, no-www

Helllo, yes i have found many questions about this on stack but my case is a bit different. I use ngnix and my website  buhehe.de is whown without www.
Okey so on ftp i have a folder `etc` in this folder there is one folder `buhehe.de` and in buhehe.de folder there is no more folder. How can i configure this site to shown as www.buhehe.de

I found this code but where shoud i place it? must i write this code ust in a text document? In which file extension must i save it?

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    return       301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    ...
}
```

Comment: _"must i write this code ust in a text document?"_ - No. You should put that in your Nginx vhost-file for the site (those are nginx directives). Where that is depends on your OS and setup. Google it.

Comment: I just use shared hosting...

Comment: Then you should ask the hosting company. Most companies have their own way of setting things up.